# Quartz.Net as windows service with jobstore in DB

Tags: database, service, quartz-scheduler

The java version of Quartz has a validation-query property which is used to check whether the database service is available. I cannot find this in the .NET version of Quartz. How does the .NET version check if the database is available after a service has been restarted or when the system is booted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has different way of checking whether a connection in the pool is still usable. The .NET connection pool does not have the concept of validation query, it's done internally within the connection pool.

So you don't need to worry about providing the validation query yourself.